# type error 'class' object not callable

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a class `MyStreamListener` that I'm trying to call from a different file, but I get the `type error 'MyStreamListener' not callable`. From what I've read when referencing user made classes, it could be because I'm trying to access a reserved keyword in python, but I've already tried changing the name of the class. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

*functionality.py*

```
from authenticate import CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
from twitter_stream import MyStreamListener

def oauth_authenticate():
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        return api

def streaming():
        api = oauth_authenticate()
        streamListener = MyStreamListener()

        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=streamListener())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "wanting to stream"
        streaming()
        print "EXITING"
```

*twitter_stream.py*

```
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

        def on_status(self, status):
                print(status.text)
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Official Tweepy documentation contains the same mistake

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the line:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = streamListener())
```

you are trying to call `streamListener` since you've got the parens there. Instead, just pass the object itself, i.e.:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=streamListener)
```